# How to call another js function after navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition completes?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Have a look at this:

```
  function doGeolocation() {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError);
       if(//here i need check)
         {
         Save();
         } 
      }
  else 
  {
    positionError(-1);
  }
}
```

So in the inner 'if' i would like to check if the navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition(); has successfully completed. Any help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition` does its own check on success, and calls a different function depending on the result.

In your function, on success a function called `positionSuccess` will be called; if the geolocation fails then `positionError` will be called.

So you need to provide a function called `positionSuccess()` which can do the saving. You don't need to do your own check.

Bear in mind that `getCurrentPosition` will take some time. This is handed off to a separate process [this is called *asynchronous processing*], and your code will continue to the next line. In your current code, execution will reach the "here I need check" test well before the geolocation result has been found. This is why there are other functions to handle success and failure — there is no guarantee when the result will be returned.

Comment: Correct..I don't want my 'save' method within the if block could start executing itself. In my Save method i'm saving the fetched coordinates info into cookies on client side and using them to point the saved location info on the map when ever required.Like you said currently its fetching the default coordinates and saving them Which of-course i don't want.

Comment: @Unknown : So only do the save operation within the "Success" callback function, which you have named `positionSuccess()`. That function is only called if the `getCurrentPosition` is successful.